# Script editor controls in browser

Tags: browsers

This is quite a mundane issue but I have a script editor used as a PDF display in a page and the options to zoom and print etc. are available in FireFox and IE but edge does not display these options, is there any way to enable this for Edge?

FireFox controls
[image]

IE Controls

[image]

Comment: I think this is a Adobe browser plugin feature we can't control i via our code.

Comment: Ah thanks for the reply, it seems that Edge does not have this support available.

Comment: I agree with little_big_thoughts. It is browser-specific what kind of controls you will get. In Chrome you will find for example a third style of the displayed controls :)